# Storing a numpy array within a iteration loop

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

**[Edit]** Actually, this is a `networkx` problem where `I` is a list of nodes in `array` format (not in the `nx.nodes` list) (in networkx); I want to record these 100 sets of nodes as `X = { I1,I2,...,I100 }` in a file. The file should contain 100 lines and each line should contain the list of nodes infected which are separated by a space. Then afterwards I have to make a graph (actually a subgraph) with each of these list of nodes Ii and find the centre of each of these subgraphs , i.e 100 centres **[Edit]**

This iteration generates a list of 100 np.arrays of I how to store all these 100 arrays in a variable so that I can use this data later on. Preferably a text file! The following doesn't work!

```
I_collect = np.zeros(5)

for counter in range(100):
     
    t, S, I = EoN.fast_SIS(g, tau, gamma, tmax = 10, initial_infecteds = 0)
    I_collect(counter) = I;
```

**error:**

```
I_collect(counter) = I;
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Comment: Use  [ ] instead of ( ) . After you have done it, you will run in another Error because I_collect is sized 5 and the loop runs up to 100: that gives IndexError ...

Comment: What are you trying to do with `I_collect(counter) = I;`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Basically, I is a list of nodes (in networkx); I want to record these 100 sets of nodes as `X = { I1,I2,...,I100 }` in a file. The file should contain 100 lines and each line should contain the list of nodes infected which are separated by a space. Then afterwards I have to make a graph (actually a subgraph) with each of these list of nodes `Ii` and find the centre of each of these subgraphs , i.e 100 centres

Comment: Please don't edit your post with the solution because now it no longer makes any sense as a question. Instead, you should accept an answer that gives the solution. If you did something different than what other's answered, you can post your own answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Claudio is correct, but there is another consideration. When you create your `np.zeros` array, you need to be aware of the shape of the array as you make it, because the calculated arrays need to be commensurate with the dimensions of the storage space.

For example, if you use your code as is, it will throw an error:(I don't know the length of your solutions or have access to the function so I have an array filled with random numbers)

```
import numpy as np
I_collect = np.zeros(5)

for idx in range(100):
    I = np.random.rand(10)
    I_collect[idx] = I
    
print(I_collect)
```

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

The correct way to go about this is to know *a priori* what the shape you want to use will be. In this case, you loop 100 times, so I assume at least one dimension is going to be of length 100, while the other is not known to me, so I use 10. Then in this example code we get

```
import numpy as np
I_collect = np.zeros((100,10)) # Preallocate an array

for idx in range(100):
    I = np.random.rand(10)
    I_collect[idx] = I
    
print(I_collect)
```

Another slower way to go about this if you don't know what shape the array will be, is to just append a list and then convert it to an array as such

```
import numpy as np
I_collect = [] # Append this empty list with values

for idx in range(100):
    I = np.random.rand(10)
    I_collect.append(I)
    
print(np.array(I_collect))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; basically I have to make an array of array, right?

Comment: Additional question; what if the size of array (which you took to be 10) which I am storing is variable? but between 0 to 22 only? Shall I make a dictionary for this case?

Comment: @Formal_that for your first question: Yes, if you want to store arrays, you need to create arrays within arrays. Python doesn't really have proper matrices, but the numpy arrays function in a similar way. For the second question, I think I understand it as you are not sure what size it will be at run time, in which case you can use the list method in the example. Alternatively you can assign space in zeros with a variable `len(<variable>)`. It is important to not make your array ragged, where they all have different sizes. Then a dictionary might be a solution.

Comment: Also be careful about changing the goal of your question after someone posts a solution to the previous version. It would be better if you opened a new question, as now this answer does not coincide with what you asked.